# How to reconfigure graphics (xorg)

Tags: 10.10, xorg, display

The display on my Laptop got corrupted after accidentally executing a script intended for my Desktop with NVidia driver.

The driver on my laptop is (lspci | grep VGA):

> Intel Corporation Mobile GM965/GL960
>   Integrated Graphics Controller (rev
>   0c)

The laptop boots up fine in FailSafe Mode but when I try to reconfigure graphics using the option on screen, nothing happens and it stays on the same screen.

I tried **sudo dpkg-reconfigure xserver-xorg** but there was no message and it came to next line.

Is there a simple way to reconfigure my XServer Display and bring to back to the earlier stage.

Comment: Without knowing what the script did, it's pure guessing. But here's mine: Move the xorg.conf (if it exists) and restart the laptop in normal mode. `sudo mv /etc/X11/xorg.conf /etc/X11/xorg.conf-broken`.

Comment: The script was from http://www.webupd8.org/2010/10/script-to-fix-ubuntu-plymouth-for.html and I have rollbacked the changes. The xorg.conf does not exist but xorg.conf.failsafe exists. As the display is fine in failsafe mode, I tried copying it as xorg.conf but that also didn't help and on normal login I go to text based login screen.

Comment: Hi hhlp, unfortunately there is no backup of xorg.conf.I had tried executing the command mentioned by you but it comes down to next line without any output on terminal.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Option 1**
You need to manually go through and undo the changes:

```
sudo apt-get remove v86d
```

Edit /etc/default/grub and reset to these two lines:

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="splash quiet"
#GRUB_GFXMODE=640x480
```

Edit `/etc/initramfs-tools/modules` and remove the line with `uvesafb` (mine has no entries beyond the initial comments).

Delete `/etc/initramfs-tools/conf.d/splash`

Run `sudo update-grub2`, `sudo update-initramfs -u`, and reboot.

**Option 2**

I've just found a script [here](http://kyleabaker.com/2010/07/11/how-to-fix-your-ubuntu-boot-screen/) that will automatically perform the above steps: [plymouth-resolution-fix-revert-back.sh.zip](http://www.kyleabaker.com/downloads/ubuntu/scripts/plymouth-resolution-fix-revert-back.sh.zip)

Comment: I had executed the script mentioned in Option 2 but it had only removed v86d. After following the instructions in Option 1, I am able to get X work in normal mode but now the plymouth boot screen is not coming and I can also not enable Compiz effects. Is there a way I can redo the graphics setup which happens on clean installation. Thanks for your answer.

Comment: Everything should be picked up automatically if you delete /etc/X11/xorg.conf

Comment: I backed up xorg.conf and restarted the machine. Plymouth is still messed up with I can live with it. https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/xserver-xorg-video-intel/+bug/474455